# Finding the vertex of the parabola parameterized by $p(t)=P_0+P_1t+P_2t^2$ for vectors $P_0, P_1, P_2$

Tags: inner-products, conic-sections, 3d, parametric

A parabola can always be described in parametric form by position vector $p(t)$,

$p(t) = P_0 + P_1 t + P_2 t^2 $

where $P_0, P_1, P_2$ are vectors in $2D$ or $3D$.

I would like to prove that the vertex of this parabola is given by

$ V = P_0 + P_1 t_1 + P_2 t_1^2 $

where $t_1$ is the solution of

$p'(t_1) \cdot p''(t_1) = 0 $

which means that $t_1$ is the solution of

$ (P_1 + 2 P_2 t) \cdot (P_2) = 0 $

therefore,

$ t_1 = -\dfrac{ P_1 \cdot P_2 }{ 2 P_2 \cdot P_2 } $

**My attempt:**

Let's express $t$ as $t = s + t_1$, where $s$ is the new parameter and $t_1$ is the fixed value we want to derive.  Substituting this

$p = P_0 + P_1 (s + t_1) + P_2 (s+t_1)^2\\
  = P_0 + P_1 t_1 + P_2 t_1^2 + (P_1 + 2 P_2 t_1 ) s + P_2 s^2 $

Now, if we select $t_1$ such that $(P_1 + 2 P_2 t_1) \perp P_2$ then

$p = V + u_1 s + u_2 s^2 $

where $u_1 \perp u_2 $ , which clearly implies that $V$ is the vertex, because then the normalized $u_1, u_2$ would constitute a rotation matrix $R = [\hat{u_1}, \hat{u_2}]$, and we would have

$ p = V + R D [s , s^2 ]^T $

where $D = \text{diag}( \|u_1\|, \|u_2\| ) $, so that if $(x', y')$ is the coordinate of $(p - V)$ in the basis $R$ then

$ x' = \| u_1 \| s $ and $y' = \|u_2 \| s^2 $

thus $(x',y') $ is on the parabola $y' = a x'^2 $ where $a = \dfrac{ \| u_2 \| }{\| u_1 \|^2 }$

And this parabola has its vertex at $(x',y') = (0,0)$ at which we have

$p = V = P_0 + P_1 t_1 + P_2 t_1^2 $

Now, to make $(P_1 + 2 P_2 t_1) \perp P_2$, we set

$(P_1 + 2 P_2 t_1) \cdot P_2 = 0$

and this results in $t_1 = - \dfrac{P_1 \cdot P_2}{2 P_2 \cdot P_2} $

Any additional help on this proof or alternative proofs is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and where you got stuck. This will help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time explaining things you already understand, duplicating your effort, or using techniques beyond your current level. Additional context such as the source of the exercise, tools available, etc, would be helpful in gauging the level of difficulty expected in the solution. (I have a calculus-based solution but am reluctant to share it.)

Comment: Thanks @Blue , I've edited my question to include my attempt.

Comment: The vertex is that point where velocity is perpendicular to acceleration: $$(P_1+2P_2t)\cdot(2P_2)=0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the vectors be $a$, $b$, $c$ so that the parabola is parameterized as
$$p(t) = a t^2 + b t + c$$
Note that chords with endpoints $p(t)$ and $p(-t)$ are parallel to $b$, and their midpoints form a line in the direction of $a$:
$$p(t)-p(-t)=2bt \qquad\qquad \frac12\left(\,p(t)+p(-t)\,\right)= at^2+ c$$

[image]

We "know" that the parabola's axis is parallel to the line of midpoints of any family of parallel chords, hence it is parallel to $a$. Finally, since the tangent at the vertex is perpendicular to the axis (hence, perpendicular to $a$), we need only solve
$$p'(t_\star)\cdot a = 0 \qquad\to\qquad (2at_\star+b)\cdot a = 0 \qquad\to\qquad t_\star = -\frac{a\cdot b}{2a\cdot a}$$

Answer (score 2):

According to proposition VI of Newton's Principia, the radius of curvature is given by
\begin{equation}
R = \frac{\|V\|^3}{\|V\times A\|}
\end{equation}
where $V = \frac{d p}{d t}$ is the velocity, $A = \frac{d V}{d t}$ is the acceleration.

In our case, $V = P_1 + 2 P_2 t$ and $A = 2 P_2$ which means that $\|V\times A\|$ is a constant equal to $2 \|P_1 \times P_2\|$. We assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are independent vectors.

It follows that the radius of curvature is minimal when $\|V\|$ is minimal, which implies $V\cdot A = 0$, hence
\begin{equation}
(P_1 + 2 P_2 t_1)\cdot 2 P_2 = 0
\end{equation}
This gives the vertex of the parabola.